# I am using Angular UI Router to switch between pages(home,news,gallery,...) but my jquery code doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

This is my AngularJS code

```
angular
    .module('portfolio', [
        'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(['$urlRouterProvider','$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider,$stateProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: '../home.php'
            })
            .state('news', {
                url: '/news',
                templateUrl: '../newsload.php'
            })
            .state('gallery', {
                url: '/gallery',
                templateUrl: '../gallery.php'
            })
            .state('contact', {
                url: '/contact',
                templateUrl: '../contact.php'
            })
            .state('about', {
                url: '/about',
                templateUrl: '../about.php'
            })
    }])
```

on page News i have some jquery animations, tranisitions, etc,.. and it doesnt work because (i think) **jquery loads before angular even populates my site**...

**The thing is I dont even know if AngularJS is the right way for what I want to achieve, I just saw it online and was impressed on how fast it is.**

What should I do?

Comment: You should do all of your animations and transitions using angular IMO, not jquery. or if you are absolutely stuck with jquery, make sure the animating code is in the proper controllers for the pages. angular has ng-animate which is pretty good,  I was looking into trying this one on a new project as well http://hendrixer.github.io/

Comment: That jQuery code will need to go inside directive(s) so element(s) it references exist when it runs. `document.ready` is virtually useless in angular app

Comment: But I have like tons of jquery code already...to show more/less, to show comments with ajax get from sql database, etc... I just dont want have pages like home.php,gallery.php, etc,... I want to have one page site and just populate different content... I dont know how to express myself properly

Comment: I dont have any directives or controllers, just the code you see above for routing

Comment: You would want to atleast set controllers(or directives) for pages, and drop the specific jquery in for them, if you have 1 global jquery file it definitely will not work (as you can see), you want it specific for each segment.

Comment: @ajmajmajma stop suggesting the code should go in controller. Controllers run before the view is generated. That is not how to handle this. Yes will need controllers to manage views

Comment: @Troix unfortunately you are building a single page app backwards. Angular would manage all the handling of getting your comments and creating the html for them. Converting would probably get rid of 50-75% of your jQuery code

Comment: Sorry yea, good catch, the directives not the controllers.

Comment: @Troix also if those pages are all standalone now ... converting to any single page methodology will require changes since your content would be ajax loaded and would need to use ajax callbacks to initialize plugins or any of your code that does animations. You will need refactoring no matter what you do

Comment: Thanks for all the commends ill see what I can do :)